# How can I hide the most visited sites on New Tap page in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I open a new tab in Chrome I get a new tab that shows the google search bar and a list of the most recent visited tabs.

How do I hide all these recent visited sites without having to remove every entry manually?

[image]

Comment: Both answers no longer appear to work in Chrome 86 for Android.

Comment: Closest I've seen is a blank homepage https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189074/android-chrome-browser-how-to-make-it-always-open-to-blank-page-and-new-tab-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Enter **chrome://flags** in the address bar
- Scroll down to **Show popular sites on the New Tab page**
- Change the setting from default to **Disabled**
- Relaunch Chrome

Comment: Didn't seem to do it, perhaps this only hides the initially populated popular links, not the most visited

Comment: I can't find this option @deb

Answer (score 1):

- Enter **chrome://flags** in the address bar
- Search for **"#explore-sites"**
- Change the setting from **default** to **Disabled**
- Relaunch Chrome

Comment: Didn't seem to be enough at this point anymore...